# get values from different rows in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe frame as below, I need to select the LONG_Y, LAT_Y from a row and the LONG_X, LAT_X from the next row in a loop, I get this for loop, but it gives me  the Y and X coordinates from the same row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[11, 12, 13], 'LAT_X':[-47.401666667,-44.198333333,-44.580753], 'LONG_X':[-22.564722221999997,-19.967777778,-22.500296], 'LAT_Y':[-47.401666667, -45.461666666999996,-46.3126902], 'LONG_Y':[-22.564722221999997,-22.9238888,-23.6378585]})

print(df)

for i in range(2):

    l1 = (df.loc[i,'LONG_Y'])
    l2 = (df.loc[i,'LAT_Y'])
    l3 = (df.loc[i,'LONG_X'])
    l4 = (df.loc[i,'LAT_X'])
    print(l1,l2,l3,l4)
```

I need to print:

```
-22.564722221999997,-47.401666667,-19.967777778, -44.198333333
```

but I get:

```
-22.564722221999997,-47.401666667,-22.564722221999997, -47.401666667
```

Comment: First: your code prints 2 lines yet you show that you get only 1 line.  Second: try `print(*df.loc[1, ['LONG_Y', 'LAT_Y', 'LONG_X', 'LAT_X']])`

Comment: look into shift

Comment: the code above gives me the coordinates from the same row, what I am trying to do it's to get the coordinates Y from row 01 an the coordinates X from row 02.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
coords = []

for i in len(df['LAT_X']):
    l1 = (df.loc[i,'LAT_X'])
    l2 = (df.loc[i,'LONG_X'])
    l3 = (df.loc[i,'LONG_X'])
    l4 = (df.loc[i,'LAT_X'])
    # Append as a coordinate:
    #coords.append([l1, l2, l3, l4])
    # Or make a flat array:
    coords.append(l1, l2, l3, l4)


for coord in coords:
    print(coord)
```